# Append a Series to a DataFrame as new columns at a specific index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, series

I have a DataFrame looking like this:

```
    Col1         Col2         Col3
1   'Content1.1' 'Content1.2' 'Content1.3' 
2   'Content2.1' 'Content2.2' 'Content2.3' 
3   'Content3.1' 'Content3.2' 'Content3.3' 
...
```

Now I want to add a Series like this:

```
Col4  'Content2.4'
Col5  'Content2.5'
Col6  'Content2.6'
```

to a *specific index* in the DataFrame, for example, at index **2** like this:

```
    Col1         Col2         Col3         Col4         Col5         Col6
1   'Content1.1' 'Content1.2' 'Content1.3' NaN          NaN          NaN
2   'Content2.1' 'Content2.2' 'Content2.3' 'Content2.4' 'Content2.5' 'Content2.6'
3   'Content3.1' 'Content3.2' 'Content3.3' NaN          NaN          NaN
...
```

For now I use the following code snippet, with `content_to_add` being the series and `data` being the DataFrame:

```
for column, value in content_to_add.iteritems():
    data.loc[index, column] = value
```

This works, but I would prefer a solution without having to iterate through the series, since that way I have to add each column one after another, with big datasets that seems like a bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `to_frame` and `concat`:

```
index = 2
pd.concat([data, content_to_add.to_frame(index).T], axis=1)

           Col1          Col2          Col3          Col4          Col5          Col6
1  'Content1.1'  'Content1.2'  'Content1.3'           NaN           NaN           NaN
2  'Content2.1'  'Content2.2'  'Content2.3'  'Content2.4'  'Content2.5'  'Content2.6'
3  'Content3.1'  'Content3.2'  'Content3.3'           NaN           NaN           NaN
```

Where the argument to `to_frame` is the index you want to concat the series rows to.